# Sprichwort "Meine Mutter sagt mir auch immer die Nachbarn sind überall schlecht"?

Tags: meaning

Gibt es das Sprichwort "Meine Mutter sagt mir auch immer die Nachbarn sind überall schlecht"?

Comment: Nein, gibt es nicht. Wo hast du das gehört oder gelesen?

Comment: Ich kannte es noch nicht, aber es gefällt mir sehr gut. :) Wo kommt es her?

Comment: Im Ruhrgebiet würde man wohl sagen: "Woanders is auch scheisse" :)

Comment: Das "Meine Mutter sagt mir auch immer" soll Teil des Sprichworts sein? M.E. gehört hinter das *immer* ein Doppelpunkt und dann groß weiter (neuer Satz).

Comment: @userunknown:Ich glaube schon, so habe ich das verstanden. Ich habe aber den Spruch eh' nicht verstanden.

Comment: @userunknown:Wieso gibst du mir einen Punkt weniger?

Comment: Wo gebe ich Dir einen Punkt weniger? Weniger als wer oder was?

Answer (score 8):

### NEIN

Dieses Sprichwort gibt es nicht. Wenn man mit einer Suchmaschine danach sucht, findet man genau eine einzige Seite, nämlich diese hier.

Ich habe diesen Satz auch noch nie gehört.

Die Frage nach der Bedeutung im Zusammenhang kann ich nicht beantworten, weil du nicht erwähnt hast in *welchem* Zusammenhang du auf diesen Satz gestoßen bist.

Comment: Das *Nein* ist noch viel zu klein :) Wäre Große XXL verfügbar, so hättes du die gerne genutzt, finde ich.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the saying traces back to

> Die Hölle, das sind die anderen (*Hell, that are the other people*)

a quote from J.P.Sartre's play 'Geschlossene Gesellschaft' (*Private Function*) denoting that the pain and suffering commonly associated with 'hell'ish environments actually stem from the way humans treat each other. The link to the original quote is flimsy at best, so it's a rather wild shot.

There also is the proverb

> Es kann der Frömmste nicht in Frieden leben, wenn es dem bösen Nachbarn nicht gefällt.
>
> (*The most pious man cannot live in peace if the vicious neighbor isn't pleased*)

attributed to Friedrich Schiller. While the saying expressly mentions some neighbor, it relativizes and therefore doesn't really come close to the meaning of your original quote either.

Answer (score 0):

Auch nein, aber es klingt mir wie eine Abwandlung von

> The grass is always greener on the other side.

Comment: The proverb addresses envy while not expressing the intent to act in a fashion detrimental to others, so it is still clearly distinct from the original phrase.

Comment: In Japan sagt man: Man kann ohne seine Verwandten leben, aber nicht ohne seine Nachbarn.", um das enge Verhaeltnis zu beschreiben. Das kann auch eine negative Konnotation haben.